# Regex in sed to replace parts of an url given a specific format

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I'm having some issues in doing a simple regex using sed.

I've to do some replacement in a sql file and I'm trying to use sed.

I should replace the url of some links. The links are in the following format:

*www.**site1**.com/blog/2012/12/12*

I would like to replace **site1** with **site2** in all links.

To find these links I've written the following regex:

```
(site1.com)\/blog\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}
```

And seems to wokr properly.

Using sed to do the replacement things I've written the following code

```
cat back.sql | sed 's:(site1.com)\/blog\/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}:site2.com:' > fixed.sql
```

But it seems is not working..

Comment: Do you ONLY want to match references to "site1.com" that are part of are "/blog/" URL?  Or will all references do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` does not support `\d` (not to my knowing at least), and supports `{4}` only with extended regular expressions.

```
sed -r 's:site1.com(/blog/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}):site2.com/\1:'
```

as a basic regular expression (requires lots of escaping):

```
sed 's:site1.com\(/blog/[0-9]\{4\}/[0-9]\{2\}/[0-9]\{2\}\):site2.com/\1:'
```

ps. you don't need to escape slashes if you use different delemiters (`:`)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be a straight substitution to me:

```
$ sed -i s/\.site1\./\.site2\./g afile.txt
```

... where `afile.txt` contains your list of sites.

If you want to output to another file, remove the `-i` and redirect the output using `>` .

Comment: A little broad, isn't this?  Probably want to expand this a little to make sure you're only catching /\.site1\./ within URLs.

Comment: @ghoti Possibly, but OP specified **Site1** with **Site2** and the format of the links does not match so it should suffice for the job needed.